doing FFT by hand with cooley-tukey

DFT matrix for size 8x8

DFT matrix for size 4x4

4x4 diagonal matrix which composed of twiddle factors

matrix multiplication of F_4 and W_4

block matrix formulation of cooley-tukey

simplified matrix

the matrix, when we join them all together to get a singular matrix.

input vector of FFT when we split the function into even and odd parts

this is the first element of the output vector when I multiply F_8 with the input vector.

But this is the first element of the output vector I get when I matrix multiply with 8x8 DFT matrix with the input vector. Why the two outputs doesn't match up? Sorry if this question is too dumb, I am trying to understand it.
